# Common invariants of virtual knots?

Tags: knot-theory, virtual-knots

When I google invariants of virtual knots (links), there's a bunch of polynomial (and other) invariants, but it's very hard to distinguish which of these are considered as somewhat classical.

In the case of normal knots, we consider classical invariants e.g. the Jones polynomial & Kauffman bracket, HOMFLYPT polynomial and Alexander polynomial...

The reason is that I'm studying a construction of knots similar to virtual ones and want to have an overview of what classical constructions work, but don't want to dig myself through various less known construcions...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you asking which invariants of classical knots are known to extend to virtual ones ?